# Mocha test fails but it shouldn't

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I've written a very basic test, the test should succeed but weirdly it doesn't.

```
    it('should add the card to the tapis', function(){
        tapis.insererTapis(new Card("O", 5));
        tapis.insererTapis(new Card("E", 3));
        tapis.tapis.should.equal([{
            suit: "E",
            val: 3
        },{
            suit: "O",
            val: 5
        }]);
        done();
    });
```

I have this weird error in the console after running `mocha test.js`

```
  0 passing (8ms)
  1 failing

  1) tapis should add the card to the tapis:

      AssertionError: expected [ { suit: 'E', val: 3 }, { suit: 'O', val: 5 } ] to be [ { suit: 'E', val: 3 }, { suit: 'O', val: 5 } ]
      + expected - actual
```

`

Is that an issue about should.js module ?

Comment: Also side note you do not need `done()` for synchronous tests such as this and for asynchronous tests where you do need it, you must both declare it as a function argument for your test function and call it when done.

Comment: Yeah I know about that, I've just added `done` to see if this error has something to do with sync/async.

Answer (score 0):

You want `.should.eql` which tests for deep equivalence as opposed to `.equal` which does a basic `===` reference identity check.

Comment: I'm not sure `deeoEqual` exist. I didn't see it int the doc. I got error `TypeError: Object #<Assertion> has no method 'deepEqual'
`

Comment: Oops, corrected. Confused should.js with chai's should module.

Comment: didn't work with `.eql` too. I must tell you that the same test code was working a few days ago. I'm not sure if I updated my modules.

Comment: I ended it by giving up the should module and working with chai.should that work great without weird errors